# Polymer JS conflicts with Rails Turbolinks

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, polymer, turbolinks

Trying to use PolymerJs with a Ruby on Rails project with Turbolinks enabled. The initial loading of Polymer components works,but when I click on a link the new page renders, but my Polymer components are not reinitialized. Instead they look as if no JS has been run on them at all.

I am loading polymer components and platform in the header, so they are not loaded with the 'page changes' (this is how turbolinks works - it only reloads the body).

I seem to be able to 'fake it' by doing the following assuming I wanted to 'refresh' my-custom-element and the core-ajax tags on my page

```
custom_elements = document.querySelectorAll("my-custom-element, core-ajax ") 
for element in custom_elements 
  element.parentNode.replaceChild(element.cloneNode(), element)
```

I am guessing there is a more idiomatic way to do it though. Also tried to call the Polymer() call inside the element again with out success. It seems like it fires properly, but there is no attachment of the shadowDom or any other activity indicating Polymer has attempted to reattach my elements. I also tried using preventDispose, but that does not seem to work as an entirely new body is being loaded from the server.

**How can I tell Polymer/Platform to reinitialize all elements on my page? What events should I be calling?**

Or if that cant be done, how do a initialize just a given polymer element.

Comment: Wrap up your function by appropriate event from these https://github.com/rails/turbolinks#events

Comment: That would be part of the question. What events should I be wrapping?- How can I tell Polymer/Platform to reinitialize all elements on my page? What events to call? Thank for the link though. It will help when I get more info on the events.

Comment: haven't used polymer before but how are you calling it in the first place?

Comment: Do you have an example running somewhere? I'm not familiar with Rails Turbolinks, but I could probably work out what's going on given an example. Polymer components shouldn't require anything more than being appended to the DOM in order to become active.

Comment: Peter Burns - I do not off hand. Polymer components do work if just added in a normal sense. Seem to be mature gems out there for better integration https://github.com/alchapone/polymer-rails. Have not personally investigated though to confirm they solve above issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Written for Turbolinks 4. Untested in Turbolinks 5**

Turbolinks replaces the Document Body after fetching it via replaceChild

https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/blob/master/lib/assets/javascripts/turbolinks.js.coffee#L97

```
document.documentElement.replaceChild(body, document.body);
```

This is not trigger the 'upgrading of elements' as it seems the Observers do not fire in this case.

I have come up with 2 different solutions to get around this.

Importing the entire body

```
$(document).on "page:change", ->
   document.documentElement.replaceChild(document.importNode(document.body, true), document.body);
```

Importing just the specific registered Polymer Elements

```
$(document).on "page:change", ->
  for polymerElement in Polymer.elements
    for domElement in document.body.querySelectorAll(polymerElement.name)
      domElement.parentNode.replaceChild(document.importNode(domElement, true), domElement);
```

**Update**

This seems to align with the officially endorsed way to handle this situation

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/polymer-dev/WaWbepYW97Q/XE3SQTyvyCUJ

Also a good use case for why this step is required

> To see why you might want to avoid changing type when adopting,
>   consider an element born in an  that gets moved into the main
>   document. You probably wouldn't want to go back through the lifecycle
>   just because it moved to a new document...

Comment: Hello,
Where do you put that code ?

I'm having issues with rails 5, turbolinks 5 and polymer...

Comment: This answer might not work with TurboLinks 5. The original solution worked when placed inside the javascript assets bundle like a normal javascript file. It did not require any special set up.