# ruby on rails 5, turbolinks 5 and polymer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymer, turbolinks

I have issues using rails 5 & turbolinks with Polymer.
I'm using the gem : 'polymer-rails'
in my app/views/layout/application.html.erb I have :

`<%= html_import_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>`

I also tried to add :

```
$(document).on("ready turbolinks:load", function() {
    return document.documentElement.replaceChild(
        document.importNode(document.body, true), document.body
    );
});
```

Both outside the body, but polymer still breaks turbolinks.
Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turbolinks and Polymer both aim to accomplish the same thing - partial page replacement but do so in different ways. Using turbolinks on top of polymer is superfluous and will give you little more than headaches.

Note that the `polymer-rails` example application does not have turbolinks installed. The solution is pretty simple - remove turbolinks from your assets manifest and gemfile.

Comment: Thanks.
Can you detail how polymer accomplish the same thing as turbolinks ?
For me it's not the same thing.
Is there a way to easily have the behavior of turbolinks with polymer ?

Comment: I would start by setting up the example app they have in the readme and get once you get a hang of how polymer works i would start adapting it to rails.

Comment: I see your point. Did that already. But you need to rewrite a lot of your front pages. Turbolinks plugs on existing pages. (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25749658/polymer-js-conflicts-with-rails-turbolinks?rq=1 from 2014)
Thanks for your time and explanations :-)

Comment: Yeah polymer is more of a single page application akin to Ember or Angular which fetches templates and JSON data. Turbolinks is much less ambitious - it just fetches HTML with ajax and uses it to replace the content in the document to speed up loading - it does not do data bindings or any more fine grained stuff.